# By using App Access Token Only, how to get the list of users of my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am new to facebook dev, I read the document but still not getting close to what I want...

by using Graph API with App Access Token, I cannot figure out how to get the list of users of my app.

I thought it will be something really simple as:
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/users

but it just do not work,

Is this just not going to work with a app access token?

My target is to know who allowed my app has permission on knowing information of their albums/photos, and the whole process is done with a app access token (so I don't need to let the user login again with my app)

OR, should I just store the User_ID on different server so that I do not need to ask Facebook to get the list for me?  <- but this sounds very stupid to me!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve from the Facebook API a complete list of all users who have authorised your app

You should track your app's users yourself in your own database - you can then use the stored user IDs at a later time if you want to check which of those users have not removed your app (via a call to `/USER_ID?fields=installed` or to `/USER_ID/permissions`)